# Draw overlapping shapes

Tags: c, opengl

I'd like to draw one shape over another, and be able to view it from another perspective.

This is what I want it to look like:

[image: A spider with 4 legs, and a circle at the end of each leg]

This is what I have so far.

```
void Draw() 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    #define r 0.5
    #define PI 3.1415926535898 
    GLint p = 100;

    double angle = 2*PI/p;

    glPolygonMode( GL_FRONT, GL_FILL );
    glColor3f(0.3,0.2,0.5);

    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
    double angle1=0.0;
    glVertex2d(r*cos(0.0),r*sin(0.0));
    int i;
    for ( i=0 ; i< p ;i++) {
        glVertex2d(r*cos(angle1),r*sin(angle1));
        angle1+=angle ;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: Thanks for answering. i want to know why everytime i try to draw the little circles on top of the first one, the 1st one disappear

Comment: No one can answer that, wothout seeing the relevant code. The code you have pasted so far is also not correct, as there is no `glEnd()` call, which could screw up everything.

Comment: Ah okay thank you i'm still learning, it's quit difficult. Can you recommend me a good book please?

Comment: Anyone please? i really need to know how to draw overlapping shapes?

Comment: Not exactly books, but have a look at the [arcsynthesis](http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/) and [open.gl](http://open.gl) tutorials.